# GROUP column mysql picking shortest name

Tags: mysql

Hi I have table in following format

```
ProductName                    CCode        MCode
Samsumg TV LED JPN             MNCC         N11
Samsung TV LED                 MNCC         N11
Samsung TV LED US              MNCC         N11   

Output I am looking for is (Shortest Name)

Samsung TV LED      MNCC       N11 (1 row)
```

Comment: Try Grouping by ccode and order by productname asc

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ProductName, CCode, MCode 
from mytable a
join (select CCode, min(length(ProductName)) as min_length
        from mytable
      group by CCode) b on a.CCode=b.CCode
where length(a.product_name) = b.min_length;
```

This is a bit awkward, but it works.  I don't know whether your search criteria should include MCode as well as you example doesn't illustrate a case where CCode and MCode differ by product.